# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, backup, dokku

I'm running a Rails app using Dokku on DigitalOcean and using Rails [backup](https://github.com/backup/backup) gem to regularly take DB backup. Recently I moved the app from one droplet to another (changed the region) and then the backup is failing to connect to the DB.

Backup model (`/root/Backup/models/oktob_database_backup.rb`)

```
Model.new(:oktob_database_backup, 'Oktob Production Database Backup') do

  ##
  # PostgreSQL [Database]
  #
  database PostgreSQL do |db|
    db.name               = ENV['DATABASE_NAME']
    db.username           = ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME']
    db.password           = ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD']
    db.host               = ENV['DATABASE_HOST']
    db.port               = ENV['DATABASE_PORT']
  end

  ##
  # Amazon Simple Storage Service [Storage]
  #
  store_with S3 do |s3|
    # AWS Credentials
    s3.access_key_id     = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
    s3.secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    s3.region            = "us-west-2"
    s3.bucket            = ENV['AWS_DATABASE_BACKUP_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3.path              = "/"
  end

  ##
  # Gzip [Compressor]
  #
  compress_with Gzip

  ##
  # Mail [Notifier]
  #
  # The default delivery method for Mail Notifiers is 'SMTP'.
  # See the documentation for other delivery options.
  #
  notify_by Mail do |mail|
    mail.on_success           = true
    mail.on_warning           = true
    mail.on_failure           = true

    mail.from                 = ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS']
    mail.to                   = ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS']
    mail.address              = "smtp.gmail.com"
    mail.port                 = 587
    mail.domain               = "oktob.io"
    mail.user_name            = ENV['SMTP_USERNAME']
    mail.password             = ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD']
    mail.authentication       = "plain"
    mail.encryption           = :starttls
  end
end
```

The configurations are stored in `/etc/environment`

```
## Database
export DATABASE_NAME=''
export DATABASE_USERNAME=''
export DATABASE_PASSWORD=''
export DATABASE_HOST=''
export DATABASE_PORT=''

## Amazon S3
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
export AWS_DATABASE_BACKUP_BUCKET_NAME=''

## Email
export EMAIL_ADDRESS=''
export SMTP_USERNAME=''
export SMTP_PASSWORD=''
```

Error message:

```
2016/08/19 11:04:34][info] Performing Backup for 'Oktob Production Database Backup (oktob_database_backup)'!
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][info] [ backup 4.2.2 : ruby 2.0.0p647 (2015-08-18 revision 51631) [x86_64-linux] ]
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn] Cleaner::Error: Cleanup Warning
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   The temporary packaging folder still exists!
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   '/root/Backup/.tmp/oktob_database_backup'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   It will now be removed.
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   Please check the log for messages and/or your notifications
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   concerning this backup: 'Oktob Production Database Backup (oktob_database_backup)'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   The temporary files which had to be removed should not have existed.
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][info] Database::PostgreSQL Started...
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][info] Using Compressor::Gzip for compression.
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][info]   Command: '/bin/gzip'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][info]   Ext: '.gz'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error] Model::Error: Backup for Oktob Production Database Backup (oktob_database_backup) Failed!
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error] --- Wrapped Exception ---
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error] Database::PostgreSQL::Error: Dump Failed!
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   Pipeline STDERR Messages:
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   (Note: may be interleaved if multiple commands returned error messages)
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "oktob" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   The following system errors were returned:
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - 'pg_dump' returned exit code: 1
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error] Backtrace:
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/lib/backup/database/postgresql.rb:72:in `perform!'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/lib/backup/model.rb:269:in `each'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/lib/backup/model.rb:269:in `block in perform!'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/lib/backup/model.rb:268:in `each'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/lib/backup/model.rb:268:in `perform!'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/lib/backup/cli.rb:156:in `perform'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/backup-4.2.2/bin/backup:5:in `<top (required)>'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/bin/backup:23:in `load'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/bin/backup:23:in `<main>'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][error]   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn] Cleaner::Error: Cleanup Warning
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   The temporary packaging folder still exists!
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   '/root/Backup/.tmp/oktob_database_backup'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   This folder may contain completed Archives and/or Database backups.
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   Make sure you check these files before the next scheduled backup for
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   'Oktob Production Database Backup (oktob_database_backup)'
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][warn]   These files will be removed at that time!
[2016/08/19 11:04:34][info] Sending notification using Notifier::Mail...
```

The app is working properly, but not sure what happened for the backup after the move. I tried to restart the DB container and the man app, but something is missing.

Comment: Can you perform `pg_dump` from hand or is it result in the same error?

Comment: @smefju I haven't tried it manually, as Dokku provides a high level way to export the DB from the container, will check the way to do it by hand

Comment: I tried this and gived the same error:`pg_dump -U postgres -h 172.17.0.1 -p 5432 oktob > name_of_backup_file`

Comment: it means that you cannot connect to database using those credentials. Make sure that they are valid and there is nothing blocking you (like pg_hba or firewall)

Comment: Thanks @smefju for the tips, will check them out